# Activity-Dialog-Activity. The Dialog is shown when pressing Back button in second Activity

Tags: android

I have a `Dialog` instance which is shown when clicking a button in an `Activity`. 
In the dialog there is another button. I call `startActivity(intent)` when clicking this button in the dialog.
So, I have an `Activity`, `Dialog`, `Activity`.
When I click back in the second activity, the dialog is shown. I want to show the first activity, not the dialog. How can I do this without calling `startActivity(intentToFirstActivity)` in the second `Activity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply call `dialog.dismiss() in your`Dialog`when you start the next`Activity`

```
//dialog creation
// set onClick
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

If this isn't working then please edit and post the `Dialog` code that you have.

Answer (score 0):

Call `dialog.dissmiss()` after calling `startActivity(Intent)` in dialog.
This will automatically take you to the first activity on back press.